# Logical replication with psycopg2 and publishers

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

There is logical replication script written in python and psycopg2:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#logical-replication-quick-start

It works. But I want to receive not all actions in the database, but only those that are specified in publisher.

For this:

1. I created publisher in source database (ver. 13.3) with name "PUB" and one table. I also deployed the second database (ver. 14.1) and created a subscription to this publication in it in order to check the functionality of the publication. And it works.
2. In psycopg2 documentation (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#replication-support-objects) and postgresql documentation (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/13/protocol-logical-replication?lang=en) I found a way to set publication_names in start_replication

```
cur.start_replication(slot_name='pytest', decode=True, options={'publication_names': 'PUB'})
```

But it didn't work. I got error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue: option "publication_names" = "PUB," is unknown
```

Actually the question. Can logical replication in psycorpg2 be associated with a subscription? And if so, how?

P.s. There is alternative (Trigger/Notify -> Listen/psycopg2), but i want to solve this problem if it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is probably "yes and no".

As [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) states in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70128094/5320906), you must use the `pgoutput` output plugin to make use of publications.  You can configure `psycopg2` to use it like this:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname='test',
    connection_factory=psycopg2.extras.LogicalReplicationConnection,
)

options = {'publication_names': 'pub', 'proto_version': '1'}
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.start_replication(slot_name='pytest', decode=False, options=options)
except psycopg2.ProgrammingError:
    cur.create_replication_slot(
        'pytest',
        output_plugin='pgoutput',
    )
    cur.start_replication(slot_name='pytest', decode=False, options=options)
```

However `pgoutput` uses a binary protocol, so the output for these statements

```
insert into table1 (col) values ('hello hello');
update table1 set col = 'hello goodbye' where id = 6;
```

is

```
b'B\x00\x00\x00\x00r!<x\x00\x02t\xc65\xbb\xb5\xd3\x00\x00jd'
b'R\x00\x00F:public\x00table1\x00d\x00\x02\x01id\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00col\x00\x00\x00\x04\x13\x00\x00\x00\x14'
b'I\x00\x00F:N\x00\x02t\x00\x00\x00\x016t\x00\x00\x00\x0bhello hello'
b'C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00r!<x\x00\x00\x00\x00r!<\xa8\x00\x02t\xc65\xbb\xb5\xd3'
b'B\x00\x00\x00\x00r!=8\x00\x02t\xc67`\xb5\xae\x00\x00je'
b'U\x00\x00F:N\x00\x02t\x00\x00\x00\x016t\x00\x00\x00\rhello goodbye'
b'C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00r!=8\x00\x00\x00\x00r!=h\x00\x02t\xc67`\xb5\xae'
```

because `psycopg2` doesn't know how to decode the messages.  You could decode them yourself, using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module from Python's standard library and the [published message formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html), or you could consider using [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) instead of `pgoutput`. `wal2json` does not currently support publications, but it does provide the means to [emulate](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json/issues/164#issuecomment-623033940) them.

Comment: I _guess_ that publications filter server-side, and wal2json filters client-side, so wal2json might not help if your concern is minimising network traffic, but that is only a guess.

Comment: In case if you want to decode pgoutput payload in python, you could use this library https://github.com/dgea005/pypgoutput

Answer (score 1):

The test_decoding plugin doesn't support the publication_names option.

The plugin used by the built-in PUBLICATION is called 'pgoutput', not 'test_decoding'.  But as far as I can tell, psycopg2 doesn't support use of that plugin.

So what you want is not supported.  I don't know if anyone is working to add support for it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that but you must use the pgoutput output plugin to make use of publications as test decoding output plugin does not support it. Also remember to use ONLY keyword while creating the publication.

`CREATE PUBLICATION name [ FOR TABLE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [, ...] | FOR ALL TABLES ] [ WITH ( publication_parameter [= value] [, ... ] ) ]`

Refer - [creating publication for only some tables in a Postgres DB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpublication.html)

Like [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) mentioned, pgoutput gives messages in encoded format and you have to decode it using algorithm specified here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html.

I have made a python code that supports both test_decoding and pgoutput along with the decoder that works perfectly OK for me. Also I have done some formatting in decoded output of pgoutput to get the messages in JSON format for better usability.

Here is the link to the same - https://github.com/PhantomHunt/cdc_postgres_logical_replication